# Button styling for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to style a control to resemble a tab control in silverlight for windows embedded.

I have started with the buttons, styling them to look like tab items.

The problem I am having is that I want the notion of an 'Active' tab and from this change either the active tab items colour or change the colour of the inactive tabs. I had a thought that adding a custom visual state of 'Active' may be an option but I'm a complete newbie to silverlight so perhaps this is not correct.

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WindowsEmbeddedSilverlightApplication1"
x:Class="WindowsEmbeddedSilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
Width="800" Height="480">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TabItemFirst" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="#FFC5EEFF" CornerRadius="5,5,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">                          
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TabItemNext" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="#C8E9F7" Margin="-1,0,0,0" CornerRadius="5,5,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentPresenter  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>                       
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Canvas.ZIndex="3" Width="75" Height="25" Style="{StaticResource TabItemFirst}" Content="Left"/>
        <Button Canvas.ZIndex="2" Width="75" Height="25" Style="{StaticResource TabItemNext}" Content="Center"/>
        <Button Canvas.ZIndex="1" Width="75" Height="25" Style="{StaticResource TabItemNext}" Content="Right"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Any pointers on how to get this functionality implemented would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the ToggleButton for this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks. It was helpful to look at the ToggleButton style xaml but it does not allow the control to retain state when another control is clicked. ie. an unrelated control on the page. I think I need to add a new state and be able to use this value associated with each tab item to know if it should have a different appearance.